# how do you access and alter an xml file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, xml

Currently i have this method for a user to log into my system:

```
<script>

function loginAccess(passwordForm){

    var pword = document.getElementById("pin").value;
    var uname = document.getElementById("username").value;

    if (uname == "Aaron" && pword == "isaloser"){
        window.location = "afterHS.html";
        return false;
    }else{
        alert("invalid username or pin")
    }};

</script>
```

but what i want to do is use details in an xml file so that a user can click to change their password.
here is my xml so far:

```
cust>
        <UserId>0001</UserId>
        <Name>Rich</Name>
        <Password>123</Password>
    </cust> 

    <cust>
        <UserId>0002</UserId>
        <Name>Aaron</Name>
        <Password>isaloser</Password>
    </cust>

    <cust>
        <UserId>0003</UserId>
        <Name>fdm</Name>
        <Password>456</Password>
    </cust>
```

how do i marry the two up so that, for example, rich can change his password to 124 and then be granted access?

Comment: Wait, what? What's your setup? Are we talking about node? If you are serving some default html over http(s) your clients won't be able to change stuff on your server via JavaScript (only). JavaScript is client-side.

Comment: it's not a real website, just practice. was using as xml as a fake mock database and wanted to change passwords and stuff by hitting this database and pushing and pulling things out of it. not possible?

Comment: You would benefit more of this practice by learning server side code as well. You can use PHP, Java, Ruby, etc... If you want to stick with Javascript, have a look at NodeJS.

Comment: ok if i change the main question to how would i go about this with php?

Comment: In this case, I suggest you take some PHP tutorials before, then, if you have a more specific problem, come back here and post it. I recommend https://www.codecademy.com/tracks/php for start. For practicing on your local machine, download XAMPP or EasyPHP, those softwares provide the structure you'll need (PHP compiler, database, etc) to simulate a server.